# C99 - An alphanumeric random char generator

Tags: c, console, c99

I have built a very small program that is a command line utility for generating alphanumeric characters of a certain length (up to a max. length) called `randchars`.

```
$ randchars 12
```

Prints twelve pseudo-random upper-/lower-case alphanumeric characters to `stdout`. The command line options `-l` and `-u` can be given, if somebody wishes to have only lower- or uppercase alphanumeric characters.

Here is the code, this is my first project while reading K&R. I know that in C99 I do not need to declare the variables on top of the functions, but I somehow grew to like it this way^^

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHARS 32

int is_lowercase(char c);
int is_uppercase(char c);
int is_digit(char c);

enum OPTS {
    MIXED,     // default
    UPPERCASE, // -u
    LOWERCASE, // -l
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned i, size, char_ok;
    srand(time(0));
    char chars[MAX_CHARS + 1];
    char rchar, c;
    enum OPTS mode;

    // get options
    if (argc < 2 || 3 < argc)
        goto error_argc;

    // size is last arg
    size = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    if (size == 0)
        goto usage;
    if (size > MAX_CHARS)
        goto error_size;

    mode = MIXED;
    if (argc == 3) {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "-l") == 0)
            mode = LOWERCASE;
        else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-u") == 0)
            mode = UPPERCASE;
        else
            goto error_opt;
    }

    // do actual computation of random chars
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        do {
            c = rand() % ('z' + 1);
            chars[i] = c;

            switch(mode) {
            case MIXED:
                char_ok = is_digit(c) || is_uppercase(c) || is_lowercase(c);
                break;
            case LOWERCASE:
                char_ok = is_digit(c) || is_lowercase(c);
                break;
            case UPPERCASE:
                char_ok = is_digit(c) || is_uppercase(c);
                break;
            }
        } while (!char_ok); // repeat if char is not ok
    }
    chars[size] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", chars);
    return 0;

error_size:
    printf("error: maximum sequence length: %u\n", MAX_CHARS);
    goto usage;
error_opt:
    printf("error: invalid option: %s\n", argv[1]);
    goto usage;
error_argc:
    printf("error: invalid amount of arguments: %u\n", argc);
    goto usage;

usage:
    printf("usage:\n\t%s [ -u | -l ] <n>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}

int is_lowercase(char c)
{
    if ('a' <= c && c <='z')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int is_uppercase(char c)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <='Z')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int is_digit(char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <='9')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is well written and organized code. Except for one part. A dreadful part. A part, that was and is the cause for many issues, even today.

## Don't use `goto`

Using `goto` [brings multiple problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto). While I won't repeat the statements from the linked question, I can certainly tell that it slowed *me* down: to understand your code, I had to repeatedly jump between lines 32+ and lines 72+.

Compare this

```
    // size is last arg
    size = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    if (size == 0)
        goto usage;
    if (size > MAX_CHARS)
        goto error_size;
```

to this:

```
    // size is last arg
    size = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    if (size == 0) {
        usage();
        return 1;
    }
    if (size > MAX_CHARS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: maximum sequence length: %u\n", MAX_CHARS);

        usage();
        return 1;
    }
```

The latter one does not force me to read other parts of the code, I immediately know what will happen, and I also know *all effects around the used variables*. `goto` does not yield any benefit here.

## Don't use `rand() % NUM` for random numbers

That's covered by the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html). Instead, use something along

```
c = '0' + rand() / (RAND_MAX / ('z' - '0' + 1) + 1)
```

This has the nice effect that all except 13 of the possible `c`s are already alphanumeric.

## Use `stderr` for error messages

For errors, you want to use `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

And that's all. As I said, the code itself is well-written. I would prefer late declared variables instead of the K&R-style early one, but that's personal preference. For argument parsing, you might want to have a look at [`getopt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#Using_POSIX_standard_getopt).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed review. Maybe another question about `goto`, since this seems to be very controversial. Looking at the second reply in the link that you posted, the use of goto here seems also fine. I have read some of the Linux kernel code and they use goto very often, so I figured for error handling it should be fine. Isn't it?

Comment: Disagree that `'0' + rand() / (RAND_MAX / ('z' - '0' + 1) + 1)` is much preferable to `rand() % NUM`.  Each has its pros and cons.  "return numbers from 0 to N-1) is poor, because the low-order bits of many random number generators are distressingly non-random." does not well apply when `N` is `'z'+1` (123) as the results depends on all bits returned by `rand()`.  Issue deeper than comments can flesh out.

Answer (score 1):

**Alphanumeric generation**

Rather than generate a random value that might be non-alphanumeric and require a re-do, consider forming only acceptable values.

```
const char *set = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int count = 26 + 10 + 26;
int offset = 0;

switch (mode) {
  case MIXED:
    break;
  case LOWERCASE:
    count = 10 + 26;
    offset = 26;
    break;
  case UPPERCASE:
    count = 10 + 26;
    break;
}

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  chars[size] = set[offset + some_good_rand() % count];
}
chars[size] = '\0';
```

- It is extremely common that `'A'-'Z'` and `'a'-'z'` are consecutive.  OP's code takes advantage of that.  Still C does not require consecutiveness.  [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). The above code does not rely on that.
- `rand()` has its strength and weakness.  It is loosely specified.   If `rand()` is insufficient, look to [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).

**Initial randomization**

`srand(time(0));` is OK.  Yet sometimes, say in a script, the program is called multiple times in the same second.  Code needs other distinguishing data to start distinctively.

If `getpid()` available, a simple improvement:

```
srand((unsigned) time(0) ^ getpid());
```

On select systems, look to even better random [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random).

**Length limitation**

`MAX_CHARS 32` seems small.  Could use a larger constant, yet any limitation less than `INT_MAX` seems unnecessarily small.  Perhaps:

- Print one character at a time, no limit
- Print in groups of `MAX_CHARS`.  Form a loop.